# PrimeFaces not rendering in Intellij 2017.2.6

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, primefaces

I am trying to create a non-maven jsf web project that uses primefaces with Intellij.[image]

The server starts, i can see the page but any primefaces tags that i have don't get rendered, this is index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
<p:outputLabel value="primefaces"/>
<h:outputLabel value="jsf"/>
</h:body>
```

When the page opens i can only see *jsf*, any primefaces `p` component that i write does not get rendered, i can easily create projects that looks just like this with netbeans but with intellij i have this issue.

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>JAX-WS endpoint</description>
    <display-name>WSServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the .iml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
<component name="FacetManager">
<facet type="web" name="Web">
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <deploymentDescriptor name="web.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
    </descriptors>
    <webroots>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web" relative="/" />
    </webroots>
  </configuration>
  <facet type="webservices" name="WebServices">
    <configuration ws.engine="Glassfish / JAX-WS 2.2 RI / Metro 1.X / JWSDP 2.2" />
  </facet>
</facet>
</component>
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
<exclude-output />
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
</content>
<orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
<orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
<orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="GlassFish 4.1.2 - JSF" level="application_server_libraries" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="Primefaces" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="GlassFish 4.1.2" level="application_server_libraries" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="JAX-WS-Glassfish / JAX-WS 2.2 RI / Metro 1.X / JWSDP 2.2" level="project" />
</component>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could help you [Intellij Jsf with tomcat issue starting web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475273/intellij-jsf-with-tomcat-issue-starting-web-page/47475638#47475638)

check if the war file contain primefaces dependency

Answer (score -1):

Fixed in the same way, project structure > artifacts > available elements > Primefaces [Intellij Jsf with tomcat issue starting web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475273/intellij-jsf-with-tomcat-issue-starting-web-page/47475638)

Comment: just upvote and accept the given answer and remove this one