# Intellij Jsf with tomcat issue starting web page

Tags: tomcat, jsf, intellij-idea

In intellij 2017.2.6 if i create a web project with Glassfish as server i don't have any problems opening the starting `index.xhtml` page, but when i create the same with Tomcat i have a 404. Since i'm new to jsf development with Intellij i wanted some help with this. This is how i create the project.
[image] It's the same way i create a Glassfish, except with webServices deselected (even if i check it i have the same issues). When tomcat starts it opens the page `http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml` as it's declared in the configuration.

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

artifacts
[image]

Comment: try to include the following dependency in pom.xml `<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
<artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
     </dependency>`

Comment: I'm not using maven, this is a basic web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: a busy cat]

check if the libraries aren't in the War/WEB-INF/libs, if not, add then.

Comment: I added the artifacts picture in the post

Comment: yes that is your problem, double click in Mojarra-2.2.1 to add it in the project